# Facebook page redirection issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

For example, if I click on https://www.facebook.com/TotalWar
I get redirected to: https://www.facebook.com/TotalWarDE.

How does this happen?

Comment: Are you asking how it happens behind the scenes or why this particular page happens to have two versions?

Answer (score 2):

Total War has created a [global page](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/331800410323820). Global Pages allow advertisers to provide localized versions of their content for their customers dependent on some self set criteria, normally where the IP address is connecting from.

Your IP is probably located in Germany and was therefore redirected to the localized version of the Total War wage.